# Let $Z\subset X$ and $x_0\in X-Z$. Show that there is a linear functional $f$ on $X$ such that $f(x_0)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in Z$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Z$ be a proper subset of an $n$-dimensional vector space $X$, and let $x_0\in (X-Z)$.  Show that there is a linear functional $f$ on $X$ such that $f(x_0)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in Z$.

I can't figure this one out. Any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

The space $X/Z$ is a finite-dimensional linear space and $x_{0}+Z \ne 0+Z$ because $x_{0}\notin Z$. Complete $\{ x_{0}+Z\}$ to a basis $\{ x_{0}+Z,x_{1}+Z,\cdots,x_{k-1}+Z\}$ of $X/Z$, where $k$ is the dimension of $X/Z$. For $x \in X$ there are unique constants $\alpha_{j}$ such that
$$
           x+Z = (\alpha_{0}x_{0}+\cdots+\alpha_{k-1}x_{k-1})+Z.
$$
Define $f(x) = \alpha_{0}$. Then $f(z)=0$ for all $z \in Z$, $f(x_{0})=1$, and $f$ is linear.